# Optomized this query

Tags: mysql

Having a structure of 3 tables

```
Table min consist of matcode,min_qty,jo_no,mr_no
Table min_out_body consist of matcode,out_qty,jo_no,mr_no
Table eu_min_out_body consist of matcode,out_qty,jo_no,mr_no
```

And data as follow:

```
[min]
matcode       min_qty           jo_no           mr_no
xxx           100               1A              A11
xxx           150               2A              A22

[min_out_body]
matcode       out_qty           jo_no           mr_no
xxx           10                1A              A11
xxx           60                1A              A11
xxx           100               2A              A22

[eu_min_out_body]
matcode       out_qty           jo_no           mr_no
xxx           20                1A              A11
xxx           50                2A              A22
```

What i am trying to achieve is to have a result:

```
matcode        min_qty          jo_no           mr_no          balance
xxx            100              1A              A11            10
xxx            150              2A              A22            0
```

Queried using following code :

```
SELECT
    min.matcode,
    min.min_qty,
    min.jo_no,
    min.mr_no
    (min.min_qty-(
        select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) 
        FROM min_out_body 
        WHERE matcode=min.matcode 
        and jo_no=min.jo_no 
        and mr_no=min.mr_no
        )-(
        select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) 
        FROM eu_min_out_body 
        WHERE matcode=min.matcode 
        and jo_no=min.jo_no 
        and mr_no=min.mr_no
        )
    ) as balance
FROM min
WHERE min.matcode = 'xxx'
    and (min.min_qty - (select
              ifnull(sum(out_qty),0)
            FROM min_out_body
            WHERE matcode = min.matcode
                and jo_no = min.jo_no
                and mr_no = min.mr_no) - (select
                            ifnull(sum(out_qty),0)
                              FROM eu_min_out_body
                              WHERE matcode = min.matcode
                              and jo_no = min.jo_no
                              and mr_no = min.mr_no)) > 0
```

I can get the result, but is there any way to simplify the query and reduce the process time?

Comment: What are the keys you are using on your tables? And what engine are you using for the tables?

Comment: Engine is myisam, for table min the keys is matcode,jo_no and wr as for other 2 tables, the key is actually doc_no which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options, and depending on the amount of data you are dealing with could perform better than other...  The first is easier readability wise but simplifies your WHERE clause and may be what you want to run with..

Wrap your query but only up to the WHERE MAT_CODE qualifier.  Let that "PQ" (PreQuery) return everything -- ALL balances.  Then from that, just apply WHERE balance > 0 vs your complex balance calculation completed AGAIN in the where clause.

```
SELECT PQ.*
   from
      ( SELECT
            min.matcode,
            min.min_qty,
            min.jo_no,
            min.mr_no
            (min.min_qty 
              - ( select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) 
                    FROM min_out_body 
                   WHERE min_no = min.min_no 
                     and matcode = min.matcode 
                     and jo_no = min.jo_no 
                     and mr_no = min.mr_no )
              - ( select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) 
                    FROM eu_min_out_body 
                   WHERE min_no=min.min_no 
                     and matcode=min.matcode 
                     and jo_no=min.jo_no 
                     and mr_no=min.mr_no ) ) as balance
           FROM 
              min
           WHERE 
                  min.matcode = 'xxx' ) PQ
   where
      balance > 0
```

If a larger data set, It looks a little larger since it does pre-aggregate queries ONCE per the "out_body" tables and groups by the components your inner field selects were dealing with.  Then LEFT JOIN to those tables.  The benefit of this approach is that it doesn't run the inner select sum() on a per record basis, and if you have 1000's of records to go through, might be a bigger time saver for you... especially if its going through MIN_OUT_BODY and EU_MIN_OUT_BODY.

By Left-Join, it's either their or not, and the IFNULL() works the same way, then the WHERE clause is the same simple readable computation of the balance WITHOUT having to requery yet again.

```
SELECT
      min.matcode,
      min.min_qty,
      min.jo_no,
      min.mr_no,
      min.min_qty - ifnull( MOB1.out_qty, 0 ) - ifnull( EMOB1.out_qty, 0 ) balance
   from
      min
         LEFT JOIN ( select 
                      mob.matcode,
                      mob.min_no,
                      mob.jo_no,
                      mob.mr_no,
                      SUM( mob.out_qty ) out_qty
                   from
                      min_out_body mob
                   where
                      mob.matcode = 'xxx'
                   group by
                      mob.matcode,
                      mob.min_no,
                      mob.jo_no,
                      mob.mr_no ) MOB1
            ON min.matcode = MOB1.matcode
            AND min.min_no = MOB1.min_no
            AND min.jo_no = MOB1.jo_no
            AND min.mr_no = MOB1.mr_no 

         LEFT JOIN ( select 
                      Emob.matcode,
                      Emob.min_no,
                      Emob.jo_no,
                      Emob.mr_no,
                      SUM( Emob.out_qty ) out_qty
                   from
                      eu_min_out_body Emob
                   where
                      Emob.matcode = 'xxx'
                   group by
                      Emob.matcode,
                      Emob.min_no,
                      Emob.jo_no,
                      Emob.mr_no ) EMOB1
            ON min.matcode = EMOB1.matcode
            AND min.min_no = EMOB1.min_no
            AND min.jo_no = EMOB1.jo_no
            AND min.mr_no = EMOB1.mr_no 
   where
          min.matcode = 'xxx'
      AND min.min_qty - ifnull( MOB1.out_qty, 0 ) - ifnull( EMOB1.out_qty, 0 ) > 0
```

Comment: just tried both query, first query returned same result as the query i posted above and optimized around 7sec(mine is 29sec with 1329 data), as for the second query, it completely insane as for the speed, it can processed 1.524.742 data for only 7 sec, but the result is not as expected. expected result should be 1329 data only.

Comment: @user3077209 you should post you table structure and some example data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com ... SQL optimization without this basic information is like `fishing without an fishing rod` and the answers will be based on guessing....

Comment: @user3077209, I don't know if you fixed my bad "mat_code" with "matcode", but I updated the query for correct column name reference.  If matcode was the issue, retry the query please...  As for your reference of 1.524.742, I left out the OUTER WHERE clause for matcode = 'xxx'... see revision and try again.

Comment: @DRapp wonderful, take 0.047sec to get the same result as what expected. Another question, by using the second query, how to get from all matcode in min table as the current sample its come with the matcode, i mean we refer the matcode from min_out_body and eu_min_out_body to min table.

Comment: @user3077209, I don't follow, but if you post as another question, and show sample data, send me a note when posted and I'll go to that too.  But if this one is resolved, upvote/checkmark so others know its resolved.  Again, put in sample data to help clarify what you want when referring to your min and eu_min tables and matcode.

Comment: @DRapp just create new question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449283/optimized-the-query but don't know how to sent you a note