# Optimized the query

Tags: mysql

Having a structure of 3 tables

```
Table min consist of matcode,min_qty,jo_no,mr_no,min_no
Table min_out_body consist of matcode,out_qty,jo_no,mr_no,min_no
Table eu_min_out_body consist of matcode,out_qty,jo_no,mr_no,min_no
```

And data as follow:

```
[min]
matcode       min_qty           jo_no           mr_no         min_no
xxx           100               1A              A11           A111
xxx           150               2A              A22           A222
yyy           100               1A              A11           A111
zzz           150               2A              A22           A222

[min_out_body]
matcode       out_qty           jo_no           mr_no         min_no
xxx           10                1A              A11           A111
xxx           60                1A              A11           A111
xxx           100               2A              A22           A222
yyy           100               1A              A11           A111

[eu_min_out_body]
matcode       out_qty           jo_no           mr_no         min_no
xxx           20                1A              A11           A111
xxx           50                2A              A22           A222
zzz           100               2A              A22           A222
```

What i am trying to achieve is to have a result:

```
matcode        min_qty          jo_no           mr_no          balance
xxx            100              1A              A11            10
zzz            150              2A              A22            50
```

Queried using following code :

```
SELECT
min.matcode,
min.min_qty,
min.jo_no,
min.mr_no,
(min.min_qty-(
    select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) 
    FROM min_out_body 
    WHERE min_no=min.min_no
    and matcode=min.matcode 
    and jo_no=min.jo_no 
    and mr_no=min.mr_no
    )-(
    select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) 
    FROM eu_min_out_body 
    WHERE min_no=min.min_no
    and matcode=min.matcode 
    and jo_no=min.jo_no 
    and mr_no=min.mr_no
    )
) as balance

FROM min
WHERE (min.min_qty - (select
              ifnull(sum(out_qty),0)
            FROM min_out_body
            WHERE min_no=min.min_no
            and matcode = min.matcode
                and jo_no = min.jo_no
                and mr_no = min.mr_no) - (select
                            ifnull(sum(out_qty),0)
                              FROM eu_min_out_body
                              WHERE min_no=min.min_no
                              and matcode = min.matcode
                              and jo_no = min.jo_no
                              and mr_no = min.mr_no)) > 0
```

I can get the result, but is there any way to simplify the query and reduce the process time?

Here is sample data from Sql Fiddle [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fb8b/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fb8b/1)

Comment: Could you explain how you have processed the 3 original tables to result in those 2 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I didn't quite understand from your comment in the previous near identical question.  The answer should actually be the same with exception of removing all the WHERE clauses where it was explicitly doing only the matcode = 'xxx'.

By removing those, you will get ALL matcode as part of the group by criteria for each min/eu_min tables.

Remove the WHERE clauses.

```
 where mob.matcode = 'xxx'

 where Emob.matcode = 'xxx'

 where min.matcode = 'xxx' AND min.min_qty ....
to just
 where min.min_qty ...
```

Comment: thanks DRapp, solved, my mistake for not take extra attention to the your query.